# How to get all non-leaf nodes in a binary search tree using recursion?

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

I am trying to get all the non-leaf nodes of a binary search tree using recursion. I can count the non-leaf nodes, but how to return them..?

```
int countNonLeafNodes(Node root)
{ 
    if (root == null || (root.left == null &&  
                         root.right == null)) 
        return 0; 
    return 1 + countNonLeafNodes(root.left) +  
               countNonLeafNodes(root.right); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try returning it as an array. So it would essentially return the array of countNonLeafNodes(root.left) with the array of countNonLeafNodes(root.right) appended to it.